# How to compare 2 input columns of binary strings using the XOR operator and assigning the output to a new column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xor

I am trying to compare two columns, "Settings 1 Values" and "Settings 2 Values", using the XOR operator, and assigning the output to the column "Delta (Pos. Difference)"

```
"Create a blank dataframe with necessary column headers"
columnNames = ["Settings 1 Values", "Settings 2 Values", "CPU Address", "FPGA Address", "Delta (Decimal)", "Delta (Pos. Difference)", "Register Name", "R/W"]
output = pd.DataFrame(columns = columnNames)


"Fill values from settings files into output dataframe"
df1 = pd.read_csv("50MHzWholeFPGA.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("75MHzWholeFPGA.csv")
spec = pd.read_excel("Mozart FPGA Register Specification.xlsx", skiprows=[0,1,2,3])
output.loc[:, "Settings 1 Values"] = df1.iloc[:, 0]
output.loc[:, "Settings 2 Values"] = df2.iloc[:, 0]
output['Delta (Decimal)'] = output['Settings 1 Values'] - output['Settings 2 Values']
set1Binary = output["Settings 1 Values"].apply(lambda x: format(int(x), 'b'))
set2Binary = output["Settings 2 Values"].apply(lambda x: format(int(x), 'b'))

"For loop generates CPU Addresses for all values"
for index, row in output.iterrows():
    output.loc[index, 'CPU Address'] = hex(CPU_START_ADDR + (2 * index))[2:]
    settingXor = int(output.loc[index, "Settings 1 Values"], 2) ^ int(output.loc(index, "Settings 2 Values"), 2)
    output.loc[index, "Delta (Pos. Difference)"] = settingXor
```

I created two variables set1Binary and set2Binary to represent the two columns but with binary strings. I would like to figure out a way to use the XOR operator to compare the two modified input columns and have the output be placed in the "Delta (Pos. Difference)" column. Thoughts?

Comment: It seems this post is a duplication of your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70264720/10452700)