# How to create a column based of the bitwise XOR of comparing two columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, binary

I am trying to fill a premade column with the bitwise XOR of two other columns

```
for index2, row in spec.iterrows():
    registerName = spec.loc[index2, 'Register Name']
    registerAddr = spec.loc[index2, 'CPU Address']
    registerAddr = '0x' + registerAddr
    settings1Val = output.loc[output['CPU Address'] == registerAddr, 'Settings 1 Values']
    settings2Val = output.loc[output['CPU Address'] == registerAddr, 'Settings 2 Values']
    fpgaAddr = spec.loc[index2, 'Address']
    readWrite = spec.loc[index2, 'R/W']
    output.loc[output['CPU Address'] == registerAddr, 'Register Name'] = registerName
    output.loc[output['CPU Address'] == registerAddr, 'R/W'] = readWrite
    output.loc[output['CPU Address'] == registerAddr, 'FPGA Address'] = fpgaAddr
    output.loc[output['CPU Address'] == registerAddr, 'Delta (Pos. Difference)'] = settings1Val ^ settings2Val
```

For the final line, I have settings1Val and settings2Val, which are just ints at a specific index within my input file. The final line works properly (it returns the bitwise XOR in int form), but when I try

```
bin(settings1Val ^ settings2Val)
```

It gives me an error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What solution is there to get that reference in binary form?

Comment: Have you tried `(settings1Val ^ settings2Val).apply('{:b}'.format)` ? (Or just `.apply(bin)` if you want the 0b prefix...?)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
(settings1Val ^ settings2Val).apply(bin)
```

Or, if you want to strip the leading `0b`:

```
(settings1Val ^ settings2Val).apply(bin).str[2:]
```

Or, as [@JonClements suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70264720/how-to-create-a-column-based-of-the-bitwise-xor-of-comparing-two-columns-pandas/70264768?noredirect=1#comment124208559_70264768), you also use this to do it without the leading `0b`:

```
(settings1Val ^ settings2Val).apply('{:b}'.format)
```

Comment: Or you can use `.apply('{:b}'.format)` to avoid generating the prefix and then removing it to start with...

Comment: Thanks so much! Still kind of new to pandas haha

Comment: Nice! Did it work?